# How to receive RabbitMQ messages in a Django app? (Celery?)

Tags: django, redis, rabbitmq, celery

We receive a RabbitMQ (or maybe Redis) message generated by an event external to our server.

How to make our Django app to be notified on such event (and execute some our code)?

Can it be done with Celery?

Comment: https://github.com/ByteInternet/django-eventhandler

Comment: Celery is designed to consume tasks on the message broker (e.g. RabbitMQ or Redis) that are also produced by Celery.  What is producing your messages?

Comment: We may get messages from WebSocket

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/jrief/django-websocket-redishttps://github.com/jrief/django-websocket-redis or something equivalent

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pika library does what I need

Answer (score 0):

This should have all of the information you need.
 The Celery task can write to the database or interact with Django through a REST API or something similar.
 https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-celery-with-rabbitmq-to-queue-tasks-on-an-ubuntu-vps.

Comment: This is not an answer to my question. I ask how to pass events from RabbitMQ to our Django app, not how to pass events from our Django app to RabbitMQ through Celery

Comment: Celery reads the events from RabbitMQ and can then pass it to Django by updating the database or calling an API, etc. You don't want to poll from Django as this would make the application unresponsive.

You probably want to make your question more specific. You said you may receive messages from Websocket. Celery can still send these messages. Update your question and I will try to make this a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at Celery Extensions & Bootsteps. It lets you write a custom AMQP message consumers.
https://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/extending.html#custom-message-consumers